# Is it possible to use CodeRay in github pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, coderay, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm using Jekyll-Bootstrap now. In my local environment, I can enable CodeRay in jekyll's _config.yml and use it in my posts without any problem. But the same code cannot work on github.

My `_config.yml` (jekyll-bootstrap configs are omitted):

```
# Use kramdown as markdown parser engine.
markdown:      kramdown
markdown_ext:  markdown,mkd,mkdn,md
textile_ext:   textile

kramdown:
  auto_ids: true
  footnote_nr: 1
  entity_output: as_char
  toc_levels: 1..6
  smart_quotes: lsquo,rsquo,ldquo,rdquo
  use_coderay: true

  coderay:
    coderay_wrap: div
    coderay_line_numbers: nil
    coderay_tab_width: 4
    coderay_bold_every: 10
    coderay_css: class
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. CodeRay is working fine locally but not on GitHub Pages. Have you made any progress on this issue since you posted the question?

Comment: No. And it seems the only way to use CodeRay is to follow the answer I mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GithHb pages runs a minimal ruby / ruby gems configuration, it will also overide some of your `_config.yml` settings see https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages for some more information.

One way around this is to build locally and then sync the generated output with GitHub pages bypassing GitGub's Jekyll configuration.

Comment: how to bypassing this issue? I am facing the same issue here, all layout are looking good only on local, thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can use kramdown with coderay on github pages. Just include

```
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  use_coderay: true
```

in your `_config.yml`.

Comment: I was using kramdown with CodeRay. But github page doesn't work as expected. I update my question to include `_config.yml` now.